# how do i ldap authenticate with ldap3 and ssl, without a cert?

Tags: python, ssl, ldap

I would like to authenticate a user with LDAPS.

So my first try was to do that in LDAP:

```
import os
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\ldap3-2.9.1\\')
import pyasn1

from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, LEVEL, ALL

server = Server('ldapip', get_info='ALL')
con=Connection(server,'aduser','adpassword', auto_bind=True)

BASE_DN = "DC=something,DC=something"

login2b = 'mylogin'
password2 = 'mypassword'

login = login2b
con.search (BASE_DN, '(&(mailNickname='+login+'))', attributes=['*'])
user_dn = str(con.entries[0]['cn'])
print('Login : ',login)
print('user_dn : ',user_dn)

if not con.rebind(user=user_dn, password=password2):
    print('error in rebind', con.result)
else:
    print('user authentificated', con.result)
```

That worked, but i cant get the SSL Version working.

Thats my code so far:

```
import os
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\ldap3-2.9.1\\')
import pyasn1
import ssl

from ldap3 import Server, Connection, Tls, SUBTREE, LEVEL, ALL

tls_configuration = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
server = Server('ldapip:636', use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration)
con=Connection(server,'aduser','adpassword', auto_bind=True)

BASE_DN = "DC=something,DC=something"
login5 = 'mylogin'
password5 = 'mypassword'

login = login5
con.search (BASE_DN, '(&(mailNickname='+login+'))', attributes=['*'])
user_dn = str(con.entries[0]['cn'])

if not con.rebind(user=user_dn, password=password5):
    print('error in rebind', con.result)
else:
    print('user authentificated', con.result)
```

The Error i get:

```
======= RESTART: C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\ldapsminimal.py ======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\ldapsminimal.py", line 13, in <module>
    con=Connection(server,'adreadonly','alsach57', auto_bind=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\ldap3-2.9.1\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 363, in __init__
    self._do_auto_bind()
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\ldap3-2.9.1\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 387, in _do_auto_bind
    self.open(read_server_info=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\ldap3-2.9.1\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 57, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\ldap3-2.9.1\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 146, in open
    raise exception_history[0][0]
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: socket ssl wrapping error: [WinError 10054] Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
```

As far as i understand the change is only the server configuration incl. the tls configuration.

- I use validate=ssl.CERT_NONE because i dont want/need to use a cert.
- I use version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 because i dont know which protocol the ldap is using.

I would like to know what i am doing wrong and a little push in the right direction...

Update:
actual code:

```
import os
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\ldap3-2.9.1\\')
import pyasn1
import ssl

from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SAFE_SYNC, Tls, NTLM, SUBTREE, LEVEL, ALL



authuser = userdn
authpassword = userpassword
aduser = aduser
adpassword = adpassword

BASE_DN = "DC=Something,DC=Something"
t = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE)
server = Server(host='ldapip', port=636, use_ssl = True, tls=t, get_info='ALL')
con = Connection(server, user=aduser, password=adpassword, client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC , auto_bind='NONE', version=3, authentication='SIMPLE')
#con.bind()
con.unbind()
```

If i bind(), rebind() or open()i get :
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: socket ssl wrapping error: [WinError 10054]
And the connection was closed.

Comment: Hi, It's been a long time... but did you manage to find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: yes i did, but i will need some time to answer....  i will try to post something in the next days, if not plz write me again.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've identified the issue (at least within my code). There seems to be an incompatibility with OpenSSL starting from Python version 3.10. Using Python 3.9 solved it.

Comment: For anyone seeing it in the future... There is also an issue with OpenSSL version 3. When using OpenSSL version 1, it all works OK, including using advanced Python versions (3.10 and above). It's not a Python issue, since OpenSSL 3 is also causing trouble in other subjects.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.18 with OpenSSL 1.1.1w, and getting this error.